# Clojure: How to implement a trie with sequences of integers rather than letters?

Tags: data-structures, hash, clojure

## Background

I am working on my own framework to numerically solve partial differential equations on simplicial complexes. Simplexes (N-dimensional triangles) are stored as ordered sets of points. Points are represented by their indexes in a separate array containing their coordinates. Each of these simplexes have a small chunk of information associated with them (like their volume). I want to implement a data structure that will allow me to efficiently perform binary operations  on pairs of keys to create new keys and pairs of values to create new values. These new key-value pairs then populate new instances of the data structure.

### Example

I have three points specified by the following list of coordinates:

`points = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)]`

These coordinates can be used to make

- One 2-simplex (triangle): (0, 1, 2)
- Three 1-simplexes (lines): (0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2)
- Three 0-simplexes (points): (0,), (1,), (2,)

## Problem

- I want to implement an associative array with at most about 10^9 key-value pairs.
- I need to efficiently create new instances of such structures by performing binary operations on the keys and values of existing instances of these structures.
- The keys are all series of positive integers ranging from 0 to N. These are always in ascending order.
- I suspect this will be simplest to implement for the case where N is known upon initialization and remains static, and this should suffice for most practical purposes. N will be somewhere on the order of 10^7.

## Partial Solution

I suspect the best solution for my purposes would be a kind of trie with keys represented as a series of integers rather than a series of characters.

After a lot of work trying different ideas in Python (what I normally code in), I strongly suspect Clojure would provide a more straightforward approach. Hence why I am asking about how to do this in Clojure.

Comment: Hi Feynman! Why do you suspect Clojure is a better fit? What shortcomings have you found in your attempt of implementing this idea in python?

Comment: Not shortcomings per se, I just explored a lot of approaches that never quite came to fruition. They all were very functional and very recursive, so I started thinking Clojure might provide a more enlightening framework. I'm not saying Python was inadequate, I just suspect the best approach to my particular problem might become more apparent within Clojure's framework

Comment: are the indexes dense or sparse?

Comment: The indexes are dense, and take on every value from 0-N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought of considering simplexes as *set*s of points? Using Clojure [sets](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.set-api.html), you'd get

- structural sharing, reducing storage requirements as tries would,
- fairly fast equality, and
- fairly fast union and intersection.

You can also quickly enumerate the facets of a simplex, such as the sides of a triangle:

```
(defn facets [s] (map #(disj s %) s))
```

For example,

```
(facets #{1 3 6})
;(#{3 6} #{1 6} #{1 3})
```

I'm thinking your solution involves building up a memoised dictionary of properties of a selection of the simplexes, in a dynamic programming style.

Comment: Wow. That actually looks very promising. I'm going to tinker with that for a day or two and probably end up accepting your answer. Since I'm new to Clojure, I just want a chance to double check it does everything I asked for.